# Memory allocation and freeing not working

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, sizeof

I'm trying to create dynamically allocated array of structures in C (VS 2022) but the program keeeps crashing while freeing the memory with problem:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9261ECF5D (ntdll.dll) in t3.exe: A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).

Code:

```
void task() {
    int i, j, size = 32;
    struct Student tmp;
    struct Student * students = (struct Student*)malloc(size*sizeof(students));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf(" %s", &students[i].name);
        scanf(" %s", &students[i].lastname);
        scanf(" %d", &students[i].index);
        scanf(" %s", &students[i].major);
        scanf(" %d", &students[i].semester);
        scanf(" %d", &students[i].grp);
    }
    free(students);
}
```

Should I also allocate every struct element manually in for loop right after getting input and then free it the same way?

Comment: `sizeof(students)` is just the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure, Try `malloc(size * sizeof(*students))`.

Comment: We also need to see the struct definition in order to answer. I'm voting to close this as simple typo for now because of the sizeof pointer bug. In case fixing that bug doesn't solve the problem, then kindly edit this into a [mcve].

Comment: O.T. there is no need to put a space before `%s` and `%d` in the `scanf` calls, that's useful with `%c`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof( students )` in this declaration

```
struct Student * students = (struct Student*)malloc(size*sizeof(students));
```

is equivalent to `sizeof( struct Student * )`. But you need to use `sizeof( struct Student )` or `sizeof( *students )` because you need to allocate an array of objects of the type `struct Student`.

Also these calls of scanf

```
scanf(" %s", &students[i].name);
scanf(" %s", &students[i].lastname);
scanf(" %s", &students[i].major);
```

you need to rewrite at least like

```
scanf(" %s", students[i].name);
scanf(" %s", students[i].lastname);
scanf(" %s", students[i].major);
```

If the data member `major` has the type `char` then you need to write

```
scanf(" %c", &students[i].major);
```

Also `name` and `lastname` (and `major` if it does not have the type char) must ne chracater arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should `malloc(sizeof(struct Student)` instead of `students` which is just a size of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
struct Student * students = (struct Student*)malloc(size*sizeof(students));
```

with

```
struct Student * students = (struct Student*)malloc(size*sizeof(struct Student));
```

Also since you are using a pointer you would need to reference the variables with `->`